# Blender tries to open all my html files after DL-ing from Blendswap

Tags: blend-files

After I downloaded some files from Blendswap (I asked them a couple times now, but got nowhere) EVERY html file I download or even bring on a removable drive from someone else's machine, my computer thinks it's a blend file.  Has the blender desktop icon and everything.

It almost seemed like blind luck that after many tries I was able to download some tutorial vids I purchased which are not related blender at all.

at Blendswap, it used to help to right click and select something like 'Save Target As..." but now it's not working any more.

Any ideas, folks?

Thanks for your time,

-Johnny7s

P.S., I put no blame on Blendswap, FYI...

Comment: If you're using Windows, you've likely set Blender as the default program to open html files by accident.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about operating system maintenance, not using Blender